# How to perform two ROBOCOPY statements from one source folder to two destination folders in one batch file?

Tags: robocopy

I have an interesting situation where I'd like to move some files from directory X to directory Y, but in order to MOVE the files without deleting the source folder, I created a log statement in said folder. A very simple version of what I'm doing is this:

```
robocopy 
    "C:\Desktop\Origin" "C:\Desktop\Destination" 
    /e /move /XF "C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log" 
    /log:"C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log"
```

This results in the moving of all files in "Origin" directory to "Destination" directory, and doesn't get rid of the "Origin" directory, as the "/e /move" flags normally would. Now, if I didn't want that log file, I could simply add this line to the code:

```
del "C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log"
```

But, I actually do want to keep this log file. I just want it somewhere else. So what I've been trying to do is to move it to directory Z with "/e /mov" or even just "/s" and then the delete. For example:

```
robocopy 
    "C:\Desktop\Origin" "C:\Desktop\Destination" 
    /e /move /XF "C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log" 
    /log:"C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log"
robocopy
    "C:\Desktop\Origin" "C:\Desktop\Destination 2" 
    /s
    del "C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log"
```

But after trying multiple times, with multiple little variations, nothing seems to happen. The first robocopy happens, but the second doesn't seem to happen at all. It seems like multiple robocopy statements can run in one batch file (which is what I want) but perhaps not from the same source directory. Does anyone know why this is the case and also how I can achieve my stated goal? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using `move "C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log" "C:\Desktop\Destination 2"` instead of RoboCopy? Or even better, just having RoboCopy write the log directly to `"C:\Desktop\Destination 2\test.log"` in the first place by changing `/log` to that folder?

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the suggestion. The reason is that I am trying to move the original files, including subdirectories and their files, from "Origin" to "Destination" and doing so using /E /MOVE deletes the original folder. Having the log file go to "Origin" means that the source directory does not get deleted (and I believe prevents it from every getting deleted). Using "C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log" "C:\Desktop\Destination 2" /MOVE also would get rid of the source directory, which is what I am trying to prevent.

Comment: However, /MOV would work, yet when I use that in the second Robocopy, it still doesn't work. As mentioned, the reason seems to be due to the fact that I am robocopying from the same source twice... but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, what I said was not to write the log to the `Origin` folder in the first place, but to output it directly to `Destination 2`, by changing `/log:"C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log"` to `/log:"C:\Desktop\Destination 2\test.log`. And the `move` I suggested is not a RoboCopy switch - it's the command line `move.exe` utility included with Windows. Type `move /?` at a command prompt for more info.

Comment: Yea, I know you were saying to write the log file to "Destination 2" directly. I am writing the log file to "Origin" intentionally so that "Origin" doesn't get deleted when the /MOVE /E switches apply. Does that make sense? There are references to this technique here: (https://serverfault.com/questions/167723/robocopy-how-to-move-the-content-of-a-directory-but-keep-the-directory/212708).

I will investigate the move.exe command. Thanks for your help, I am completely new to CMD prompt, Robocopy, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of Ken White, I found a solution to this. If you use MOVE.EXE, it works just as expected.

```
robocopy 
    "C:\Desktop\Origin" "C:\Desktop\Destination" 
    /e /move /XF "C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log" 
    /log:"C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log"
move
    "C:\Desktop\Origin\test.log" "C:\Desktop\Destination 2"
```

One thing to note is that you can't use /LOG+: with this method, since you'd be writing the log file to a location where no log file exists, since it had been moved previously to "Destination 2". However, even the normal log files include the *EXTRA files already in the directory.